# Can I solve by ADMM?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I wonder if I can solve the following with ADMM:

$$ \min_{A,C}||C||_* +\lambda||X-A||_F^2 $$ with the constraint $$A=AC$$.

My doubts are because usually the general form for ADMM is 
$$ \min_{x,z} f(x) + g(z) $$ with the constraint $$Ax+Bz=c$$

and in my problem, I have multiplication of A and C.
What should I do ?

Comment: The product of $A$ and $C$ makes this non-convex.

Comment: Any idea how can I solve such problems?